# Need help with a zeta-like function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Some time ago I found interesting modifications to Euler's prime product that produces a square number and its square root.  The parts that were still unknown were the corresponding sums. I have finally found the sum which produces the square.

The solution is to use $\textit{5-rough}$ numbers---numbers whose least prime factors are $\geq 5$. See [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RoughNumber.html) and [Wiki.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_number)

At [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A007310) we find this formula for $\textit{5-rough}$ numbers:

```
FORMULA (6n + (-1)^n - 3)/2 by Antonio Esposito, Jan 18 2002
```

**Edit--- We include 1 in this formula even though it is not considered a *rough* number**
$$
\psi (n)\equiv\frac{1}{2} \left(6 n+(-1)^n-3\right)
$$
**Edit2--- We replace the function with one that converges faster.**
$$
\psi (n)\equiv\frac{(6 n-5) (6 n-1)}{\sqrt{72 (n-1) n+26}}
$$
Here we show the sum and product that produce the square number:
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \psi (n)^{-2} = \prod _{n=3}^{\infty } 
(1-(p_n)^{-2})^{-1} = \frac{\pi^2}{9}
$$
Here we show the sum and product that produce the square root:
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \phi (n)^{-2} = \prod _{n=1}^{\infty } 
(1-(6 n)^{-2})^{-1} = \frac{\pi}{3}
$$
A function for the second sum is still unknown:
$$
\phi (n)\equiv\textbf{?}
$$
I tried using $\textit{3-smooth}$ numbers---numbers whose prime factors are $\leq 3$, but that converges to $1.499999\ldots$

Here is one function that uses an alternating series, but I would prefer something that can be squared during the summation (to make it more zeta-like).
$$
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(\frac{1}{6 n+5}+\frac{1}{6 n+1}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3}
$$

My question: Does anyone have any ideas on how to craft this last function?

Comment: It seems you talk about Dirichlet L-functions and their special values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reworking the alternating sum, I found, for $s=2$:
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{(6 n-1)^s}+\frac{1}{(6 n-5)^s}\right) = \prod _{n=3}^{\infty } 
(1-(p_n)^{-s})^{-1} = \frac{\pi^2}{9}
$$

The LHS is the only formula that is equal to the RHS for all $s>2$.

Therefore, the square root product is only a curiousity and not worth further attention.

*I am accepting this answer to remove the post from the unanswered queue.*